# Move Azure VM from one account to another in the same Bizspark subscription

Tags: virtual-machines, azure

I have a Bizspark subscription with 2 accounts using some of their services. One account which is mine, has 2 VMs running. Last week I started another VM without noticing that this one was going to exceed the subscription bill, so yesterday both (the other one was used a few hours to test something) VMs went down with a mail from MS telling me that they shut both because I excedeed the monthly bill, great, now I have 2 internet facing services down. Trying to figure how to solve this problem without waiting 15 days before new credit is available, I thought of moving both VMs to account B which has all of the monthly credit available, is it possible?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a question for the vendor.

Comment: the vendor now recommends stackexchange as forums...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that Virtual Machines disks are stored as VHDs on an Azure Storage. Said that, basically this is what you need to do:

1. Create a storage in your new subscription
2. Take note of the disks associated with your VM. Select VM -> Dashboard -> Get the list of disks at the bottom.
3. Take note of the VM settings like network, size, etc.
4. Delete the VM (WITHOUT DELETING THE VHDS!!) or just keep it turned off.
5. Use Azcopy to copy the VHD from current storage (old sub) to the new storage (new sub)
6. Create a Disk using that copied VHD on the new sub. Navigate VMs >> Disks Tab >> Create (bottom bar) >> Select the copied VHD
7. Create a VM using this disk. New >> Compute >> VM >> From Gallery >> My Disks >> Select disk >> Replicate VM configuration.

**Getting Started with the AzCopy Command-Line Utility**

http://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/storage-use-azcopy/

Comment: Thank you, I tried that but it seems that as my subscription is temporarily disabled, I don't have permission to do it:


`Finished 0 of total 0 file(s).
[2015/04/12 18:49:58][ERROR] Error parsing source location "[...].vhd": The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.
The account being accessed does not have sufficient permissions to execute this operation.`

Comment: how to do step 1? in the new Azure Portal I don't find this option (is that a way to do it in the classic/old portal?)

Answer (score 0):

You can do AzCopy to complete this, and you also nned to set the container as public container, otherwise you will not have permission to finish this task.